# NaN when adding or subtracting points from saved houses

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have this HTML script with some JavaScript code for a school project. It will receive a house ID and the number of points that house has (kind of like Harry Potter).

The data is being pulled from a few text files by a Flask python script rendering the HTML sites. The data gets over okay, but I want the houses and their points to display when the site loads, and that works, but if I add or remove points, it says NaN.

I did notice that when loading a saved house, it names the house `0` and the point value is `None`.

Here is my HTML script:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--Styles have been removed because they are unnecessary-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="button-container">
        <button class="button" onclick="createHouse()">Create House</button>
    </div>

    <div class="house-container" id="houses">
        {% for house_id, points in house_points.items() %}
        <div class="house" id="{{ house_id }}">
            <div class="house-name">{{ house_id }}</div>
            <div class="house-icon">
                <div class="circle">
                    <span class="inner-circle">{{ points }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div id="modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close-button" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
            <div class="house-name" id="houseName"></div>
            <div class="house-icon">
                <div class="circle">
                    <span class="inner-circle"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container-house">
                <button class="button" onclick="addPoints(1)" data-houseid="{{ house_id }}">+1</button>
                <button class="button" onclick="subtractPoints(1)" data-houseid="{{ house_id }}">-1</button>
                <button class="button" onclick="addPoints(5)" data-houseid="{{ house_id }}">+5</button>
                <button class="button" onclick="subtractPoints(5)" data-houseid="{{ house_id }}">-5</button>
            </div>
            <div class="textbox-container">
                <input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="Reason">
            </div>            
            <div class="button-container-house">
                <button class="button submit-button" onclick="submitPoints()">Submit</button>
                <button class="button cancel-button" onclick="cancelPoints()">Cancel</button>
                <button class="button remove-button" onclick="removeHouse()">Remove</button>
            </div>
            <div id="outerNumber"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var savedPoints = {}
        var unsavedPoints = {};

        // Function to send data to Flask via a POST request
        function sendData(url, data) {
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    // Handle successful response
                    console.log('Data sent successfully');
                } else {
                    // Handle error response
                    console.error('Failed to send data:', response.status);
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                // Handle fetch error
                console.error('Error sending data:', error);
            });
        }

        function createHouse() {
            var houseName = prompt("Enter the name for the new house:");
            if (houseName) {
                var houseId = houseName.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase();
                savedPoints[houseId] = 0;
                unsavedPoints[houseId] = 0;

                var houseContainer = document.getElementById("houses");

                var houseDiv = document.createElement("div");
                houseDiv.id = houseId;
                houseDiv.classList.add("house");

                var houseNameDiv = document.createElement("div");
                houseNameDiv.classList.add("house-name");
                houseNameDiv.textContent = houseName;
                houseDiv.appendChild(houseNameDiv);

                var houseIconDiv = document.createElement("div");
                houseIconDiv.classList.add("house-icon");

                var circleDiv = document.createElement("div");
                circleDiv.classList.add("circle");

                var innerCircleSpan = document.createElement("span");
                innerCircleSpan.classList.add("inner-circle");
                innerCircleSpan.textContent = savedPoints[houseId];

                circleDiv.appendChild(innerCircleSpan);
                houseIconDiv.appendChild(circleDiv);
                houseDiv.appendChild(houseIconDiv);

                houseDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    openModal(houseId);
                });

                houseContainer.appendChild(houseDiv);

                sendData('/create_house', { 'house_id': houseId });
            }
        }

        function openModal(houseId) {
            console.log('Open Modal:', houseId, savedPoints, unsavedPoints);

            var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
            var houseName = document.getElementById("houseName");
            var innerCircle = document.querySelector("#modal .inner-circle");
            var textbox = document.querySelector("#modal .textbox");

            houseName.textContent = houseId;
            modal.dataset.houseId = houseId;

            if (unsavedPoints.hasOwnProperty(houseId)) {
                var unsavedPointsValue = parseInt(unsavedPoints[houseId]);
                console.log("Unsaved Points:", unsavedPointsValue);
                innerCircle.textContent = unsavedPointsValue;
            } else if (savedPoints.hasOwnProperty(houseId)) {
                var savedPointsValue = parseInt(savedPoints[houseId].points);
                console.log("Saved Points:", savedPointsValue);
                innerCircle.textContent = savedPointsValue;
            } else {
                innerCircle.textContent = "";
            }

            textbox.value = "";

            modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        function closeModal() {
            var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        function addPoints(value) {
            var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
            var houseId = modal.dataset.houseId;
            var innerCircle = document.querySelector("#modal .inner-circle");
            var points = unsavedPoints.hasOwnProperty(houseId) ? unsavedPoints[houseId] : savedPoints[houseId];
            points = parseInt(points) + value;
            unsavedPoints[houseId] = points;
            innerCircle.textContent = points.toString();
        }

        function subtractPoints(value) {
            var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
            var houseId = modal.dataset.houseId;
            var innerCircle = document.querySelector("#modal .inner-circle");
            var points = unsavedPoints.hasOwnProperty(houseId) ? unsavedPoints[houseId] : savedPoints[houseId];
            points = parseInt(points) - value;
            unsavedPoints[houseId] = points;
            innerCircle.textContent = points.toString();
        }

        function cancelPoints() {
            var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
            var houseId = modal.dataset.houseId;
            var innerCircle = document.querySelector("#modal .inner-circle");
            var points = savedPoints[houseId];
            delete unsavedPoints[houseId];
            innerCircle.textContent = parseInt(points, 10);
            closeModal();
        }

        function submitPoints() {
            var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
            var houseId = modal.dataset.houseId;

            var data = {
                house_id: houseId,
                points: Number(unsavedPoints[houseId] || savedPoints[houseId]),
                reason: document.querySelector("#modal .textbox").value
            };

            sendData('/save_house_points', data);
            closeModal();
        }

        function fetchHousePoints() {
            fetch('/get_house_points')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('Fetched Data:', data);

                    savedPoints = data;
                    unsavedPoints = {}; // Reset unsavedPoints

                    var houseContainer = document.getElementById('houses');
                    houseContainer.innerHTML = '';

                    Object.keys(data).forEach((houseId, index) => {
                        var points = parseInt(data[houseId].points);

                        var houseDiv = document.createElement('div');
                        houseDiv.id = houseId;
                        houseDiv.classList.add('house');

                        var houseNameDiv = document.createElement('div');
                        houseNameDiv.classList.add('house-name');
                        houseNameDiv.textContent = houseId;
                        houseDiv.appendChild(houseNameDiv);

                        var houseIconDiv = document.createElement('div');
                        houseIconDiv.classList.add('house-icon');

                        var circleDiv = document.createElement('div');
                        circleDiv.classList.add('circle');

                        var innerCircleSpan = document.createElement('span');
                        innerCircleSpan.classList.add('inner-circle');
                        innerCircleSpan.textContent = points.toString();

                        circleDiv.appendChild(innerCircleSpan);
                        houseIconDiv.appendChild(circleDiv);
                        houseDiv.appendChild(houseIconDiv);

                        houseDiv.addEventListener('click', function () {
                            openModal(houseId);
                        });

                        houseContainer.appendChild(houseDiv);
                    });
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching house points:', error);
                });
        }

            window.addEventListener('load', fetchHousePoints);



        function removeHouse() {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this house?")) {
                var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
                var houseId = modal.dataset.houseId;

                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('houseId', houseId);

                fetch('/remove_house', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: formData
                }).then(response => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        var house = document.getElementById(houseId).parentNode.parentNode;
                        house.parentNode.removeChild(house);
                        delete savedPoints[houseId];
                        delete unsavedPoints[houseId];
                        closeModal();
                        console.log('House removed successfully');
                    } else {
                        console.error('Failed to remove house:', response.status);
                    }
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error removing house:', error);
                });
            }
            closeModal();
        }

        function updateHousePoints() {
            var houseContainer = document.getElementById("houses");
            houseContainer.innerHTML = ""; // Clear the container

            Object.entries(savedPoints).forEach(function ([houseId, points]) {
                var houseDiv = document.createElement("div");
                houseDiv.id = houseId;
                houseDiv.classList.add("house");

                var houseNameDiv = document.createElement("div");
                houseNameDiv.classList.add("house-name");
                houseNameDiv.textContent = houseId;
                houseDiv.appendChild(houseNameDiv);

                var houseIconDiv = document.createElement("div");
                houseIconDiv.classList.add("house-icon");

                var circleDiv = document.createElement("div");
                circleDiv.classList.add("circle");

                var innerCircleSpan = document.createElement("span");
                innerCircleSpan.classList.add("inner-circle");
                innerCircleSpan.textContent = parseInt(points, 10);

                circleDiv.appendChild(innerCircleSpan);
                houseIconDiv.appendChild(circleDiv);
                houseDiv.appendChild(houseIconDiv);

                houseDiv.addEventListener("click", function () {
                openModal(houseId);
                });

                houseContainer.appendChild(houseDiv);
            });
            }

        // Fetch house points and update the page on load
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            fetchHousePoints();
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting to be able to be able to add and subtract points from the saved houses without error.

Comment: "*sorry its kind of long*": You don't have to say sorry. Just reduce it and isolate the problem so as to make a [mre]. This would increases the chance of your question being noticed and therefore you would be more likely to get answers.

Comment: Use `curl` to issue a POST of `/save_house_points`, followed by a GET of `/get_house_points`. Verify that the house ID of interest is being properly updated.

Comment: I removed the unnecessary stuff like styles and headers. Now its just some buttons linking to the JavaScript functions which is where I suspect something is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <!--Styles have been removed because they are unnecessary-->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="button-container">
        <button class="button" onclick="createHouse()">Create House</button>
    </div>

    <div class="house-container" id="houses">
        {% for house_id, points in house_points.items() %}
        <div class="house" id="{{ house_id }}">
            <div class="house-name">{{ house_id }}</div>
            <div class="house-icon">
                <div class="circle">
                    <span class="inner-circle">{{ points }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div id="modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close-button" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
            <div class="house-name" id="houseName"></div>
            <div class="house-icon">
                <div class="circle">
                    <span class="inner-circle"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="button-container-house">
                <button class="button" onclick="addPoints(1)">+1</button>
                <button class="button" onclick="subtractPoints(1)">-1</button>
                <button class="button" onclick="addPoints(5)">+5</button>
                <button class="button" onclick="subtractPoints(5)">-5</button>
            </div>
            <div class="textbox-container">
                <input type="text" class="textbox" placeholder="Reason">
            </div>
            <div class="button-container-house">
                <button class="button submit-button" onclick="submitPoints()">Submit</button>
                <button class="button cancel-button" onclick="cancelPoints()">Cancel</button>
                <button class="button remove-button" onclick="removeHouse()">Remove</button>
            </div>
            <div id="outerNumber"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var savedPoints = {};
        var unsavedPoints = {};
        function sendData(url, data) {
            fetch(url, {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(data),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.ok) {
                        console.log('Data sent successfully');
                    } else {
                        console.error('Failed to send data:', response.status);
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error sending data:', error);
                });
        }

        function createHouse() {
            var houseName = prompt("Enter the name for the new house:");
            if (houseName) {
                var houseId = houseName.replace(/\s+/g, "-").toLowerCase();
                savedPoints[houseId] = 0;
                unsavedPoints[houseId] = 0;

                var houseContainer = document.getElementById("houses");

                var houseDiv = document.createElement("div");
                houseDiv.id = houseId;
                houseDiv.classList.add("house");

                var houseNameDiv = document.createElement("div");
                houseNameDiv.classList.add("house-name");
                houseNameDiv.textContent = houseName;
                houseDiv.appendChild(houseNameDiv);

                var houseIconDiv = document.createElement("div");
                houseIconDiv.classList.add("house-icon");

                var circleDiv = document.createElement("div");
                circleDiv.classList.add("circle");

                var innerCircleSpan = document.createElement("span");
                innerCircleSpan.classList.add("inner-circle");
                innerCircleSpan.textContent = savedPoints[houseId];

                circleDiv.appendChild(innerCircleSpan);
                houseIconDiv.appendChild(circleDiv);
                houseDiv.appendChild(houseIconDiv);

                houseDiv.addEventListener("click", function () {
                    openModal(houseId);
                });

                houseContainer.appendChild(houseDiv);

                sendData('/create_house', { 'house_id': houseId });
            }
        }

        function openModal(houseId) {
            console.log('Open Modal:', houseId, savedPoints, unsavedPoints);

            var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
            var houseName = document.getElementById("houseName");
            var innerCircle = document.querySelector("#modal .inner-circle");
            var textbox = document.querySelector("#modal .textbox");

            houseName.textContent = houseId;
            modal.dataset.houseId = houseId;

            if (unsavedPoints.hasOwnProperty(houseId)) {
                var unsavedPointsValue = parseInt(unsavedPoints[houseId]);
                console.log("Unsaved Points:", unsavedPointsValue);
                innerCircle.textContent = unsavedPointsValue;
            } else if (savedPoints.hasOwnProperty(houseId)) {
                var savedPointsValue = parseInt(savedPoints[houseId]);
                console.log("Saved Points:", savedPointsValue);
                innerCircle.textContent = savedPointsValue;
            } else {
                innerCircle.textContent = "";
            }

            textbox.value = "";

            modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        function closeModal() {
            var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        function addPoints(value) {
    var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    var houseId = modal.dataset.houseId;
    var innerCircle = document.querySelector("#modal .inner-circle");
    var points = unsavedPoints.hasOwnProperty(houseId) ? unsavedPoints[houseId] : savedPoints[houseId];
    
    if (!isNaN(points)) {
        points = parseInt(points) + value;
        unsavedPoints[houseId] = points;
        innerCircle.textContent = points.toString();
        var houseElement = document.getElementById(houseId);
        if (houseElement) {
            var innerCircleElement = houseElement.querySelector(".inner-circle");
            if (innerCircleElement) {
                innerCircleElement.textContent = points.toString();
            }
        }
    }
}

function subtractPoints(value) {
    var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
    var houseId = modal.dataset.houseId;
    var innerCircle = document.querySelector("#modal .inner-circle");
    var points = unsavedPoints.hasOwnProperty(houseId) ? unsavedPoints[houseId] : savedPoints[houseId];
    
    if (!isNaN(points)) {
        points = parseInt(points) - value;
        unsavedPoints[houseId] = points;
        innerCircle.textContent = points.toString();
        var houseElement = document.getElementById(houseId);
        if (houseElement) {
            var innerCircleElement = houseElement.querySelector(".inner-circle");
            if (innerCircleElement) {
                innerCircleElement.textContent = points.toString();
            }
        }
    }
}

        function cancelPoints() {
            var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
            var houseId = modal.dataset.houseId;
            var innerCircle = document.querySelector("#modal .inner-circle");
            var points = savedPoints[houseId];
            delete unsavedPoints[houseId];
            innerCircle.textContent = parseInt(points, 10);
            closeModal();
        }

        function submitPoints() {
            var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
            var houseId = modal.dataset.houseId;

            var data = {
                house_id: houseId,
                points: Number(unsavedPoints[houseId] || savedPoints[houseId]),
                reason: document.querySelector("#modal .textbox").value
            };

            sendData('/save_house_points', data);
            savedPoints[houseId] = data.points; 
            closeModal();
        }

        function fetchHousePoints() {
            fetch('/get_house_points')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('Fetched Data:', data);

                    savedPoints = data;
                    unsavedPoints = {}; 

                    updateHousePoints();
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error fetching house points:', error);
                });
        }

        function removeHouse() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this house?")) {
        var modal = document.getElementById("modal");
        var houseId = modal.dataset.houseId;

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('houseId', houseId);

        fetch('/remove_house', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
        })
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                var house = document.getElementById(houseId);
                if (house) {
                    house.parentNode.removeChild(house);
                }
                delete savedPoints[houseId];
                delete unsavedPoints[houseId];
                closeModal();
                console.log('House removed successfully');
            } else {
                console.error('Failed to remove house:', response.status);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error removing house:', error);
        });
    }
    closeModal();
}


        function updateHousePoints() {
    var houseContainer = document.getElementById("houses");
    houseContainer.innerHTML = ""; 

    Object.entries(savedPoints).forEach(function ([houseId, points]) {
        var houseDiv = document.createElement("div");
        houseDiv.id = houseId;
        houseDiv.classList.add("house");

        var houseNameDiv = document.createElement("div");
        houseNameDiv.classList.add("house-name");
        houseNameDiv.textContent = houseId;
        houseDiv.appendChild(houseNameDiv);

        var houseIconDiv = document.createElement("div");
        houseIconDiv.classList.add("house-icon");

        var circleDiv = document.createElement("div");
        circleDiv.classList.add("circle");

        var innerCircleSpan = document.createElement("span");
        innerCircleSpan.classList.add("inner-circle");
        
        if (!isNaN(points)) { 
            innerCircleSpan.textContent = parseInt(points, 10);
        }

        circleDiv.appendChild(innerCircleSpan);
        houseIconDiv.appendChild(circleDiv);
        houseDiv.appendChild(houseIconDiv);

        houseDiv.addEventListener("click", function () {
            openModal(houseId);
        });

        houseContainer.appendChild(houseDiv);
    });
}

        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            fetchHousePoints();
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).